# Nested form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-attributes

I'm trying to save nested form, not sure how to make it work.
Can't save private_message with 'body'.

```
@private_message_topic.private_messages.build
```

it builds private_message with private_message_topic_id set. not sure how to add params[:body] though

Hope you can help me. Thanks.

```
class PrivateMessageTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"

  has_many :private_messages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :private_messages
end


class PrivateMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"
  belongs_to :private_message_topic
end


class PrivateMessageTopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_user
  before_action :find_private_message, only: [:show]

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @private_message_topic = current_user.sent_messages.build
    @private_message_topic.private_messages.build
  end

  def create
    @private_message_topic = current_user.sent_messages.build(private_message_topic_params)
    @private_message_topic.recipient = @user

    if @private_message_topic.save
      #Todo
    else
      redirect_to action: :new
      flash.alert = "oops!"
    end
  end

  def inbox
    @inbox_messages = @user.inbox_messages
  end

  def sent
    @sent_messages = @user.sent_messages
  end

  private
    def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def find_private_message
      @private_message = PrivateMessageTopic.find(params[:id])
    end

    def private_message_topic_params
      params.require(:private_message_topic).permit(:title, private_messages_attributes: [:body])
    end
end


private_message_topics/_form

= simple_form_for @private_message_topic, url: user_private_message_topics_path, method: :post do |form|
  = form.input :title

  = form.simple_fields_for @private_message_topic.private_messages.new do |form|
    = form.input :body

  = form.submit
```

Comment: Please post your `User` model.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9351436  @San

Comment: I would recommend using either `nested_form` or `cocoon` gem.

Answer (score 0):

Change `current_user.sent_messages.build` to `current_user.sent_messages.new` in both `new` and `create` methods in your controller.

And in your form, there is no need to do `private_message.new` since you are already building it in the controller. The form should look like this:

**private_message_topics/_form**

```
= simple_form_for @private_message_topic, url: user_private_message_topics_path, method: :post do |form|
  = form.input :title

  = form.fields_for :private_messages do |f|
    = f.input :body

  = form.submit
```

Also, I think there is no need to specify url and method in the form declaration. Rails automatically sets up correct url and method.

Comment: still it doesn't create private_message associated to this private_message_topic

Comment: Can you share the params hash that is being posted to the controller.

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem. Are you using a gem for nested form like `nested_form` or `cocoon`?